# What counts as a gravitational wave?

Tags: gravity, speed-of-light, gravitational-waves

Non-physicist asking.

Suppose two massive bodies approach each other at great speed. They pass non-destructively past each other and continue on, in their new directions.

Does the gravitational force between them constitute a wave (of very long wavelength). The magnitude increases as they approach; reaches a peak when they are close and then decreases indefinitely as they separate. Is it a standing wave? If it's a standing wave then it's not travelling at the speed of light (?).

Can someone elucidate?

Comment: [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09702) is a paper on this process.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe (local changes in the gravitational field between two masses) would not be considered a wave.  However, the interaction between the two masses - and the changes in the gravitational field during their interaction - would *launch* a gravitational disturbance that travels away from the masses, out to infinity; and the traveling disturbance would be considered a wave.